# Extract page name from URL

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

This bookmarklet is working as expected.

```
javascript:{window.location='http://bing.com/search?q='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)}
```

But it sends the entire URL to bing. Instead I need only the last part to be sent. For e.g. If I am on the page

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286483.aspx

Then it should send only "aa286483.aspx" to bing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `window.location.pathname`, which will return `/en-us/library/aa286483.aspx`.

A direct approach it will be:

```
window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
function getFileName(url) {
  return url.split("/").pop();
}
var url = "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286483.aspx";
console.log(getFileName(url));
```

And note that you should take care of url parameters (aa286483.aspx/?id=2 for example) too if it is important in your case. I don't include it here since your question is about file name only.

Answer (score 2):

Just read past the last path delimiter?

```
var url  = window.location.pathname;
var last = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
var array = window.location.href.split('/'),
     res = "";

 while(res === "") {
   res = array.pop();
 }

 return res;
```

this will prevent you from returning an empty string if the URL ends with '/'